# Asynchronous loop inside an asynchronous loop: a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some javascript code which does the following:

1. Read a .txt file and fill up an array of objects
2. Loop through these itens
3. Loop through an array of links inside each of these itens and make a request using nightmarejs
4. Write the result in Sql Server

My code is like this:

```
    const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const async = require('async');
    const sql = require('mssql');

    var links = recuperarLinks();

    function recuperarLinks(){
    //Read the txt file and return an array
    }

    const bigFunction = () => {     
        var aparelho = '';  
        async.eachSeries(links, async function (link) {
            console.log('Zip Code: ' + link.zipCode);
            async.eachSeries(link.links, async function(url){
                console.log('URL: ' + url);
                try {
                    await nightmare.goto(link2)
                        .evaluate(function () {
                            //return some elements
                        })
                        .end()
                        .then(function (result) {
                            //ajust the result
                            dadosAjustados.forEach(function (obj) {
                                //save the data 
                                saveDatabase(obj, link.cep);                           
                            });             
                        });
                } catch (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }
            }
            }, function(err){
                console.log('Erro: ');
                console.log(err);
            })        
        }, function (erro) {
            if (erro) {
                console.log('Erro: ');
                console.log(erro);
            }
        });
    }

async function salvarBanco(dados, cep){
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
      user: 'sa',
      password: 'xxx',
      server: 'xxx',  
      database: 'xxx'
    });
    pool.connect().then(function(){
        const request = new sql.Request(pool);
        const insert = "some insert"
        request.query(insert).then(function(recordset){
            console.log('Dado inserido');           
            pool.close();
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            pool.close();
        })
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });        
}

lerArquivo();
```

It works fine, but i'm finding this async loop inside another async loop like a hack of some sort.

My outputs are something like this:

```
Fetching Data from cep 1
Fetching Data from url 1
Fetching Data from cep 2
Fetching Data from url 2
Fetching Data from cep 3
Fetching Data from url 3
```

Then it starts making the requests. Is there a better (and possibly a correct way) of doing this?

Comment: I really hope your SQL password is a fake one (even though there is no server or such, it still makes sense not to share it here ;) ) (note that it will still be in the edit log of this question...)

Comment: it is not effective since you are fetching URL only one-by-one instead of making that in parallel

Comment: It doesn't really have to be effective, since it will be something that will run as a job

Comment: I am assuming the question is purely about the `const bigFunction` as the rest of the code doesn't really seem to be related to it, neither the function which is called at the end (it's not even there), why not simply reduce the `links` to concat the `links.links` and just looping that one? You also don't seem to return anything from bigFunction, so it's kind of a fire and forget thingie which might not be the easiest thing to know it has finished? Do you really need async in a scraper? It anyhow will take some time, I don't really see the advantage on a single instance of nightmare

Comment: Also note that your try catch block really seem to make the error callback useless... Also, if your code is working, but you just want to have it reviewed, take a look at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: You should *absolutely* not mix `async`/`await` promise syntax with the async.js library. Drop callbacks and use the modern style.

Comment: If I were teaching a junior programmer or doing a code review for code from any level of developer, I would never allow code that mixes promises and the callback-based `async` library.  It's just mixing two completely different programming styles for both control flow and error handling and all you get is a very hard to understand mess.  Pick one model or the other.  Don't mix.  Personally, it seems to me that the future of the language is Promises for both async control flow and error propagation so that's what I would use.

Comment: It's perfectly fine and necessary sometimes to nest loops that involve asynchronous operations.  But, the loops have to be designed carefully to both work appropriately and to be clean, readable and maintainable code.  Your `bigFunction()` does not seem to be either to me with your mix of async coding styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize your calls to `nightmare.goto()` and you want to simplify your code which is what you seem to be trying to do with `await`, then you can avoid mixing the callback-based async library with promises and accomplish your goal by only using promises like this:

```
async function bigFunction() {     
    var aparelho = '';  
    for (let link of links) {
        for (let url of link.links) {
            try {
                let result = await nightmare.goto(url).evaluate(function () {
                        //return some elements
                }).end();
                //ajust the result
                await Promise.all(dadosAjustados.map(obj => saveDatabase(obj, link.cep)));
            } catch (e) {
                // log error and continue processing
                console.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Asynchronous loop inside an asynchronous loop: a good idea?

It's perfectly fine and necessary sometimes to nest loops that involve asynchronous operations. But, the loops have to be designed carefully to both work appropriately and to be clean, readable and maintainable code. Your `bigFunction()` does not seem to be either to me with your mix of async coding styles.

> It works fine, but i'm finding this async loop inside another async loop like a hack of some sort.

If I were teaching a junior programmer or doing a code review for code from any level of developer, I would never allow code that mixes promises and the callback-based async library. It's just mixing two completely different programming styles for both control flow and error handling and all you get is a very hard to understand mess. Pick one model or the other. Don't mix. Personally, it seems to me that the future of the language is Promises for both async control flow and error propagation so that's what I would use.

Note: This appears to be pseudo-code because some references used in this code are not used or defined such as `result` and `dadosAjustados`.  So, you will have to adapt this concept to your real code.  For the future, we can offer you much more complete answers and often make suggested improvements that you're not even aware of if you include your real code, not an abbreviated pseudo-code.

Comment: @joaovictor - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.